# Issue with query, likely foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I'm setting up 3 Mysql create table queries below. The 3rd one works, the first 2 fail and throw this message:

> The plugin generated 132 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

Here are the 3 queries. I am guessing the foreign key statement is bad in query 2 (for #1 I have no clue). Is that the cause or is it something else?

```
$createCouponTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons (
    couponId mediumint not null auto_increment unique,
    primary key (couponId),
    totalHits mediumint not nu ll,
    isText boolean not null,
    imageUrl text(1000)
    )";

    $createTargetTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}frequentVisitorCoupons_targets (
      targetId medium int not null auto_increment unique,
      primary key (targetId),
      isSitewide tinyint(1) not null,
      targetUrl varchar(500),
      displayThreshold tinyint(5) not null default 20,
      offerCutoff tinyint(5),
      fk_coupons_targets mediumint not null unique,
      foreign key fk_coupons_targets references wp_frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons(couponId) on delete cascade
    )";

    $createVisitsTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}frequentVisitorCoupons_visits (
      visitId mediumint(9) not null auto_increment unique,
      primary key (visitId),
      visitorId mediumint(9) not null,
      urlVisited varchar(500) not null
    )";
```

Comment: *"I am guessing"* ...don't guess. Find an error log.

Answer (score 2):

Spurious spaces:

```
    totalHits mediumint not nu ll,
                              ^
  targetId medium int not null auto_increment unique,
                 ^
```

need parens:

```
foreign key fk_coupons_targets references wp_frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons(couponId) on delete cascade
           ^                  ^
```